# Session time-out in webservices

Tags: android, web-services

I am developing a Restful Webservice using Eclipse and an android application. User logs in using its username and password on the android application which is checked against the database at the server side(using this web service).

Now, I want to maintain a session for which the user will remain logged in, that is, the user does not have to log in again and again whenever he re-opens the application.

How to do it? I searched on net but I could not find an accurate solution. Kindly help with the appropriate solution. Ask if more information is required.

Answer (score 2):

use **Shared Preferences** to save session data .
there are good tutorials :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

http://androidexample.com/Android_Session_Management_Using_SharedPreferences_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=127

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two ways. One is storing them in a global variables and second is storing the data in shared preferences. The problem with storing data in global variable is data will be lost once user closes the application, but storing the data in shared preferences will be persistent even though user closes the application. Here is the complete example:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/